# How to shoot a transparent item for later background removal?

Tags: product-photography, background-removal

I have a transparent item and want to take photo which i can use later without using the background, yet not losing the effect on the transparent item.

Comment: Can mention what transparent item this is? A water glass, etc? What background(s) might you want to end up with?

Answer (score 1):

Try shooting against a black background. When you place the object on a new layer reduce the transparency.

When you light the transparent object you do not light the object. You light the things that are being reflected by the transparent object. Make sure the lighting in the original setting matched the lighting in the other background.

Answer (score 0):

The bad news.

There are many types of transparent objects, but in general it is almost impossible to have a good looking fake background on a transparent object.

The background interacts with the object, refraction, difraction, reflections, difusing, and it is very hard to diferentiate the both after.

My only advice is that you need to photograph it on a plain color simmilar to what you pretend to fake it later.